# tabindex for custom radio input without javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to have a radio button where I can navigate and select the value using the arrow on the keyboard.

I have no problem making one:

```
const BareRadio = ({
  id,
  name,
  value,
  defaultChecked,
  onChange,
  children,
  tabIndex
}) => (
  <div
  >
    <input
      type='radio'
      defaultChecked={defaultChecked}
      value={value}
      id={id}
      name={name}
      onChange={onChange}
      tabIndex={tabIndex}
    />
    <label htmlFor={id}>
      <span >
        <span ></span>
      </span>
      <span>{children}</span>
    </label>
  </div>
);
```

But now I have a custom radio button, which the structure hide the input tag and use css to mimic the label. Can I still use tabindex to achieve the same thing? or I need to use javascript?

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-7lgfpk?file=index.tsx